# Dois foreach em um select

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite. Como faço para usar sois foreach para verificar se os nomes são iguais e assim deixá-los com selecionados.

Segue os retornos das variáveis:

```
$risco_e =

    Array
    (
        [0] => Postura Inadequada
        [1] => Postura Inadequada por tempo Indetermidado
    )




$risco_ergonomico = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [idRiscoErgonomico] =>; 5
                [riscoErgonomico_Nome] =>; Esforço Fisico
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [idRiscoErgonomico] =>; 1
                [riscoErgonomico_Nome] =>; Não Exposto
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [idRiscoErgonomico] =>; 2
                [riscoErgonomico_Nome] =>; Odontologos
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [idRiscoErgonomico] =>; 3
                [riscoErgonomico_Nome] =>; Posições Encomodas
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [idRiscoErgonomico] =>; 6
                [riscoErgonomico_Nome] =>; Postura Inadequada
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [idRiscoErgonomico] =>; 4
                [riscoErgonomico_Nome] =>; Postura Inadequada por tempo Indetermidado
            )

    )
```

Tentei assim e meio que deu certo, os valores igual ficam selecionados, porém todos são duplicados, como mostra na foto a seguir:

```
<select>
  <?php

    str = trim($result->setor_RiscoErgonomico, ',');
    $risco_e = explode(',', $str);

    foreach ($risco_ergonomico as $riscoErgonomico)
    { 
       foreach ($risco_e as $re)
       {  ?>

          <option <?=$re == $riscoErgonomico->riscoErgonomico_Nome ? "selected" : ""?>><?=$riscoErgonomico->riscoErgonomico_Nome?></option>

       <?php }                        
     } 

  ?>
</select>
```

[image: Foto de anexo de teste do código]

Comment: Não entendi a sua duvida

Comment: Normalmente era pra aparecer apenas um nome de cada risco, porém ao realizar os dois foreach estão sendo duplicados os valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudei um pouco seu foreach:

```
foreach ($risco_ergonomico as $riscoErgonomico)
{ 
    $descricao = $riscoErgonomico->riscoErgonomico_Nome;
    $selectd = "";
    foreach ($risco_e as $re) {
        if($re == $riscoErgonomico->riscoErgonomico_Nome){
            $selectd = "selected";
        }
   }
   echo("<option $selectd>$descricao</option>");
 }
```

Assim os valores não ficaram duplicados. A ideia é essa, agora é você melhorar o código.

Comment: Obrigado irmão. Tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode tentar usar o method in_array, para verificar se o dado já existe dentro do array e com isso negar que o dado entre:

```
foreach ($risco_ergonomico as $riscoErgonomico)
{ 
   foreach ($risco_e as $re)
   {  ?>

      if(!in_array($riscoErgonomico, $re)){
        <option <?=$re == $riscoErgonomico->riscoErgonomico_Nome ? "selected" : ""?>><?=$riscoErgonomico->riscoErgonomico_Nome?></option>
      }

   <?php }                        
 }
```

Também teria a opção de pegar um array e jogar dentro do outro usando "array_unique" se todas as chaves forem iguais:

```
$risco_ergonomico = array_unique($risco_e);
```

Comment: Nenhum das opções deram certas amigo. :(  O pior que esse sistema preciso entregar essa semana.

Comment: Dentro do in_array, no primeiro parâmetro tenta passar pelo nome, não deu certo porque não são arrays identicos:

!in_array($riscoErgonomico->riscoErgonomico_Nome, $re)

Comment: Outra coisa, acredito que vc não precisa fazer dois arrays, somente um percorrendo o $risco_e e colocando ele dentro de $risco_ergonomico.

Comment: Poderia me explicar melhor Paulo?

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?