# Array de informações do banco de dados em codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Por exemplo, estou mandando um array de id [0] => 1, [1] => 3 e quero mostrar isso no meu html em forma de resultado. No caso, que buscar no banco o com o primeiro id salvar no array e depois buscar com o segundo id e por fim retornar um array contendo os outros dois arrays.

```
public function getRecibos($codigosRecibo)
{      
    $result = array('');

    foreach ($codigosRecibo as $codigoRecibo)
    {
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->where('idRecibo', $codigoRecibo);
        $this->db->from('recibo');
        $result = $this->db->get();
    }       
        return $result->result();
}
```

Fiz assim porém ele está fazendo as índices do array serm sempre 0

```
public function getRecibos($codigosRecibo)
{      
    $result = array('');

    foreach ($codigosRecibo as $codigoRecibo)
    {
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->where('idRecibo', $codigoRecibo);
        $this->db->from('recibo');
        $result[] = $this->db->get();
    }       
        return $result->result();
}
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idRecibo] => 2
            [recibo_Recebi] => Condomínio Edifício Dona Gladis 
            [recibo_Relativo] => 02 consultas periódicas - Catia da Silva, Gabriel Vinholes 
            [recibo_Valor] => 64,00 (sessenta e quatro reais)
            [recibo_Dia] => 01
            [recibo_Mes] => Março 
            [recibo_Ano] => 2019
            [recibo_Data] => 2019-03-01
            [recibo_Forma_pgto] => 0
            [recibo_idCheque] => 0
            [recibo_Pago] => s
            [recibo_DataPgto] => 2019-03-13
            [idCheque] => 
            [cheque_Emitente] => 
            [cheque_Numero] => 
            [cheque_Banco] => 
            [cheque_Cic_Cnpj] => 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idRecibo] => 1
            [recibo_Recebi] => Condomínio Edifício Porto Vecchio 
            [recibo_Relativo] => 01 consulta periódica - Ronaldo Faria 
            [recibo_Valor] => 32,00 (trinta e dois reais)
            [recibo_Dia] => 01
            [recibo_Mes] => Março
            [recibo_Ano] => 2019
            [recibo_Data] => 2019-03-01
            [recibo_Forma_pgto] => 0
            [recibo_idCheque] => 0
            [recibo_Pago] => s
            [recibo_DataPgto] => 2019-03-13
            [idCheque] => 
            [cheque_Emitente] => 
            [cheque_Numero] => 
            [cheque_Banco] => 
            [cheque_Cic_Cnpj] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude o seu código, porque realmente você está fazendo errado, ou seja, em vez de passar os valores para o `array`, você está retornando somente o resultado, exemplo:

```
public function getRecibos($codigosRecibo)
{      
    $result = array();

    foreach ($codigosRecibo as $codigoRecibo)
    {
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->where('idRecibo', $codigoRecibo);
        $this->db->from('recibo');
        $result[] = $this->db->get()->result(); // acumulando o resultado
    }       
    return $result;
}
```

mas, pelo visto existe uma outra forma melhor e também que proporciona um desempenho satisfatório utilizando `where_in`, ***exemplo***:

```
public function getRecibos($codigosRecibo)
{   
      $this->db->select('*'); 
      $this->db->where_in('idRecibo', $codigosRecibo);
      $this->db->from('recibo');
      return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)</sup>

Comment: Valeu fera. Funcionou perfeitamente. <3

Comment: Se você poder me ajudar mais uma vez, tem outro post meu que estou com dificuldades. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/367425/dois-foreach-em-um-select

Answer (score 1):

Se você alterar o seu array para

```
foreach ($codigosRecibo as $key => $codigoRecibo)
```

E no bd->get() alterar para

```
$result[$key] = $this->db->get();
```